# zsh:killed /usr/libexec/java_home -V after running /usr/libexec/java_home -V

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, zsh

I am trying to run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v`, and I am getting this error :
`zsh:killed /usr/libexec/java_home -V`

What did i try?

1. Reinstalling brew.
2. Changing shell to bash. It throws `killed : 9`

When did it started happening?

I run the following commands

```
 1.cd /usr/libexec
    
 2. ./java_home
```

It returned me the path of directory where java is installed, but after that when i tried to run this command, it throw error.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Killed 9 implies wrong architecture (Intel/ARM). On which architecture are you?

Comment: I am on ARM achitechture.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the machine resolved this issue. I don't know how!